# Plugin activation/deactivation page transitions with page parameters, then vanished

Tags: notices

When activating or deactivating WordPress plugin, within a blink of eye some URL parameters just appear and vanish, can't even snap them so fast. And then the admin notice appears:

> Plugin **activated**.

I wonder what those parameters are? How the admin notices appears, and how the parameters vanished with the blink of an eye?